# How do I upload an image to firebase and then return the URL?

Tags: flutter, firebase, url, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do the following:

1. Take a web URL for an image and upload it into firebase
2. Once the image is uploaded return the firebase URL for the image

```
Future<String> portrait(String imageinput) async {
  // Add your function code here!

  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageinput));

  final imageBytes = response.bodyBytes;

  final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('images/${DateTime.now().toString()}.jpg');

  final uploadTask = storageRef.putData(imageBytes);
  await uploadTask;

  final String imageUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
  return imageUrl;
}
```

Comment: You can add image itself to firebase storage and get the url for that image.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code , use with your requirement

First, follow `sendImage` method then `storage method` then `chatservice`

```
class StorageMethods {
  static final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Reference _storageReference;

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> uploadImageToStorage(File imageFile, String fileName) async {
    try {
      _storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
      UploadTask storageUploadTask = _storageReference.putFile(imageFile);
      var url = await (await storageUploadTask.whenComplete(() {})).ref.getDownloadURL();
      var name = _storageReference.name;
      print("image name ======>> $name");
      print("image url ======>> $url");

      return {"url": url, "name": name};

      return {"url": url, "name": name};
    } catch (e) {
      print("uploadImageToStorage exception ======>> $e");
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> uploadImage({
    @required String type,
    @required String fileName,
    @required File file,
    @required String receiverId,
    @required String senderId,
    @required ChatImageUploadProvider imageUploadProvider,
    @required String sender,
    String senderProfile,
    var numberOfMessage,
  }) async {
    // Set some loading value to db and show it to user
    imageUploadProvider.setToLoading();

    // Get url from the image bucket
    Map<String, dynamic> uploadMap = await uploadImageToStorage(file, fileName);

    // Hide loading
    imageUploadProvider.setToIdle();

    chatService.setImageMsg(
      type,
      uploadMap["url"],
      receiverId,
      senderId,
      uploadMap["name"],
      sender,
      senderProfile,
      numberOfMessage,
    );

    return uploadMap;
  }
```

Inside the chatService method :

```
Future<void> setImageMsg(String fileType, String url, String receiverId, String senderId, String bucketName,
      String username, String senderProfile, var numberOfMessage) async {
    Message message;

    message = Message.imageMessage(
        message: fileType == "image" ? "Photo Message" : "DOCUMENT",
        receiverId: receiverId,
        senderId: senderId,
        senderProfile: senderProfile,
        fileUrl: url,
        timestamp: Timestamp.now(),
        type: fileType,
        bucketName: bucketName,
        numberOfMessage: numberOfMessage);

    var map = message.toImageMap();

    await _messageCollection.doc(message.senderId).collection(message.receiverId).add(map);

    _messageCollection.doc(message.receiverId).collection(message.senderId).add(map);
  }
```

This is my sendImage method

```
void sendImage(String fileType, String fileName, String filePath) async {
    try {
      File selectedFile = File(filePath);
      var uploadMap = await _storageMethods.uploadImage(
        type: fileType,
        fileName: fileName,
        senderProfile: _currentUser.profilePhoto,
        file: selectedFile,
        receiverId: widget.receiverId,
        senderId: _currentUser.firebaseId,
        imageUploadProvider: _imageUploadProvider,
        sender: _currentUser.firebaseId,
        numberOfMessage: ++messageCount,
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

After uploading a file, you can get a URL to download the file by calling the getDownloadUrl() method on the Reference:

```
await mountainsRef.getDownloadURL();
```

For updated documentation please check
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files